# Do an action when a time counter gets a new integer

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to store some values in a while with a variable counter t in a certain way that for example, t reaches 2, certain value gets stored, t reaches 3, value gets stored and so on until 20:

In this example t starts at 1, and dt=0.1. I want that when we reach t=2 do the action:

```py
while t<t_final:
   t += dt
   tint = int(t)
   for i in range(20):
        if tint == int(i):
            action
            break
```

But I'm not sure if the break does what I want. Which is the best approach?

Comment: Why not use match-case with tint? why the for loop?

Comment: Sorry @RyanZhang. What u mean by match-case?

Comment: By the way the if statement should have two "equals" signs [if tint == int(i)].

Comment: Fixed it, was a typo, thanks! @NoDakker

Comment: As your program is written now, the "break" statement will "break" out of the "for" loop only.

Comment: Yeah @NoDakker, thats an aggresive try but I know that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i undesrstand correctly dt is a float (0.1 for example). If you want to add 0.1 every time but you want the action happen only when the number is a integer(AKA has no decimals) you will have a floating point problem. for example 0+0.1+0.1+0.1... will never give you 15, it will give you, 14.999999999999963.

You could say if the numbers after the decimal point have a value less than (and some confindence interval) assume is integer:

```
t= 0
t_final = 20
dt = 0.1
while t<t_final:
    t += dt
    tDecimals = t%1
    if tDecimals < dt: # less than dt or less than 0.1
        print(int(t))
    #action
```

Or, i think this is a better option, use a flag and: if the value of t are greater than the value of last t by at least 1 do the action

```
t= 0
lastInteger = t-1
t_final = 20
dt = 0.1
while t<t_final:
    t += dt
    if lastInteger + 1 < t:
        lastInteger = int(t)
        print(int(t))
        #action
```

And another option is use Decimals (are better than floats for a lot of operations)

```
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = 9 # number of 0 after decimal points 
                              #  that decimal will use and save

t= decimal.Decimal('0')
t_final = 20
dt = decimal.Decimal('0.1')
while t<t_final:
t += dt
for i in range(20):
        if t == i:
            Action
            break
```

Comment: and,in yout question
for i in range(20):
        if tint == int(i):
            action
could be written as
if tint in range(20):

Comment: Better to initialize your `Decimal` with a string: `dt = decimal.Decimal('0.1')`.

Comment: And no need to convert `i` to `Decimal`, it compares against `int` just fine. For that matter `Decimal%1` works too.